# Yii2 Advanced app init.bat fgets not working

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, fgets

When starting init.bat the init php script will not wait/hold for input while using fgets.

PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2019 10:14:18)

Comment: If you are on Windows the 7.4.0 version had a bug that might be impacting this. 7.4.1 fixed it.

Comment: Yes this works!!!

Answer (score 1):

All worked after changing the init file:

**edit: upgrading php from 7.4.0 to 7.4.1 worked for me! (better)**

```
$answer = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$answer = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Into:

```
$answer = trim(readline("Number: "));
$answer = trim(readline("Answer: "));
```